# Can i select the only packages I used within my maven dependecies to export a runnable jar in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ffmpeg, pom.xml

I'm using Javacpp in a Java application. Inside my pom I have:

org.bytedeco
    javacv-platform
    1.5.1

and the only imports I have in the project are related with ffmpeg and opencv. However, when I create the runnable Jar, it is huge (hundreds of megabytes) because it has a lot of jars from other packages that come with javacv-platform that are useless for me (I can see them inside maven dependecies). Is there anyway to remove the packages I never used inside this dependency? Beacause I can see all of them inside the runnable jar I create.

Comment: Yes, see here for a list of options: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just exclude what you don't need, like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${javacv-platform.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javacv-platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>flycapture-platform</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javacv-platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>libfreenect-platform</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But there is actually no code in the JAR of "javacv-platform", so you might want to include just what you want instead (which I assume is just "javacv", "opencv-platform" and "ffmpeg-platform").