# Process vide files to take screen grabs in java spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bytedeco-javacv

I am using JavaCV library with ffmpeg bindings to process video files and taking screen grabs at specific frames.
Adding JavaCV library dependency to my spring project increases the size of my jar file from around 90Mb > 1+ Gb.
This is a big issue becuase my project is deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk that accepts a max size of 500 Mb for a jar file.

Need help to resolve this issue with the jar file or else any other alternate library that could do this.

**What I tried:** I have removed all accept the abosultely necessary dependencies in my project to reduce the jar size.
I have also tried to find alternate solutions but couldnt get anything.
My pom file looks like

````
<dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.550</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- APACHE POI Dependency for excel -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
            <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>```
````

Comment: Have you tried to use the profiles explained on this page https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies ?

Comment: Yes. I solved it by adding exclusions for all the libraries I didn't need within the package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i select the only packages I used within my maven dependecies to export a runnable jar in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147604/can-i-select-the-only-packages-i-used-within-my-maven-dependecies-to-export-a-ru)

Comment: Yes, This is what I have linked with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by excluding the libraries I didn't need in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flandmark-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artoolkitplus-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>videoinput-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>videoinput</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artoolkitplus</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>librealsense2-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>librealsense2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>librealsense</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libfreenect2-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libfreenect-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openblas-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>leptonica-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>librealsense-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libdc1394</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flycapture</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openblas</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>leptonica</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flandmark</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>librealsense2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libfreenect2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libdc1394-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libfreenect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tesseract</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tesseract-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flycapture-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javacpp-platform</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javacpp-presets</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Reference: [Can i select the only packages I used within my maven dependecies to export a runnable jar in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147604/can-i-select-the-only-packages-i-used-within-my-maven-dependecies-to-export-a-ru)